# appcelerator: Pushing new window in to modal window

Tags: ios, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Hi everyone i have a question regarding modal views in Appcelerator. Currently i have a modal view showing up in the app with a navigation window (see below).

```
//this is my modal 
<Alloy>
    <NavigationWindow id="win1" platform="ios">
        <Window id="win2" title="Red Window" backgroundColor="red">

        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>

//this is the window i want to push in this modal view. 
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win3" title="Blue Window" backgroundColor="blue">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

In my win2.js (which is my parent window and also my modal) i have the following

```
var window = $.win2;
var navigationwindow = $.win1;

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window'
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    navigationwindow.openWindow(win3, {animated:true});
});
```

But this doesn't do anything. Is it even possible to push windows in an modal window?

I would be very glad if someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openWindow()` *is* the right way to push a new window, but in your `win2.js` controller the `$` variable will only hold references to elements you created in `win2.xml` and not the view where you created the Navigation Window. In the controller of that view, add a reference like `Alloy.Globals.nav = $.win1` (be sure to clean up after closing the Navigation Window) which you then can use in `win2.js`.

Comment: He Fokke thank you i already solved the problem :) thanks for the answer. Im looking forward to meetup in Amsterdam , if im right you organising that.

Comment: I sure am! See you there